Getting extra null rows when I am trying read excel file with EPPlus OfficeOpenXml
I have an Excel file with 4 sheets. However, it is behaving incorrectly when I am reading the first sheet in my C# (.NET Core 3.1) code.
The sheet has around 350-450 entries, sometimes it reads only 4 empty rows and at times the 450 rows but still 4 extra empty rows. Then I deleted a few empty rows from the end so it starts reading correctly.
This is the code I am using:
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> ReadSheet(ExcelWorksheet worksheet)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("No. of rows (including header) = " + worksheet.Rows.Count());
    
            var headers = worksheet.Cells["A1:ZZ1"].Select(c => c.Text).ToList();
            _logger.LogInformation("No. of headers > " + headers.Count);
    
            List<Dictionary<string, string>> sheetData = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
            int count = worksheet.Rows.Count();

            for (int row = 2; row <= worksheet.Rows.Count(); row++)
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> rowData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                for (int col = 1; col <= headers.Count; col++)
                {
                    rowData[headers[col - 1]] = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Text;
                }

                sheetData.Add(rowData);
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("Number of rows stored:" + sheetData.Count);
    
            return sheetData;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Exception:" + ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }

I am using the same code to read all other sheets and they have correct row count.
This Excel I am using is prepared using Java code and has no extra rows added to it. I cannot manually keep deleting extra empty rows from the end.
Please advice. Thanks in advance!
EDIT:
I have 435 rows populated (with header).
And I am getting :
No. of rows (including header) = worksheet.Rows.Count() = 439
No. of rows (including header) = worksheet.Dimensions.Rows = 442

I always use worksheet.Dimensions.Rows.

@itsme86 This is considering even more null rows.
I have 435 rows populated (with header).
And I am getting :
No. of rows (including header) = worksheet.Rows.Count() = 439
No. of rows (including header) = worksheet.Dimensions.Rows = 442
